# How can I write a sed script to delete numbers from a line?

Tags: linux, shell-script, scripting, sed

**Sample File**

```
a.b.gg3d 0000000001 0000000001 y
a.b.112a 0000000000 0000000001 y
a.b.gg3s 0000000001 0000000001 y
a.b.1111 0000000000 0000000001 m
```

I have a file that includes about three thousand unique lines, similar to the sample above.  I want to use sed to remove the "xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx" numbers from each line.  Using the sample above, I would like the sed script to produce the following output:

```
a.b.gg3d y
a.b.112a y
a.b.gg3s y
a.b.1111 m
```

How can I accomplish this?  Is there a string of commands to tell sed something like "delete all numbers after the first whitespace, but leave the last character"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given this input, you want to keep the first and last fields. Pretty simple with awk:

```
awk '{print $1, $NF}' filename
```

Using sed, this will replace all space delimited digit-only words:

```
sed ':a; s/ [[:digit:]]\+ / /; ta'
```

Comment: I understand that the s means substitute and the forward slashes are delimiters, but what do the following commands mean?     :a;      \+    and ; ta

Comment: :a is a label, ta means "go to a": in short, it is a loop

Comment: And `sed 's/ [[:digit:] ]\+ / /'` can do it the same

Comment: I was thinking along the lines of enzotib, but went with `sed 's/[[:space:]][[:digit:]]\+//g'` which removes one or more numbers `[[:digit:]]\+` proceeded by whitespace (tabs, spaces) `[:space:]`, and also specified `/g` to the options, to do it for all occurrences (and not just the first)

Comment: The reason I searched for the trailing space in a loop was to avoid matching `" 123abc"` -- i.e. to ensure that the word was composed only with digits.

Comment: Not a big deal in this case, but `[:space:]` includes "vertical" whitespace like carriage return and newline, and `[:blank:]` is only horizontal whitespace like tab and space.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution only using `cut`, that will print the first and fourth column:

```
cut -d' ' -f1,4 < samplefile.txt
```

Comment: By far the most appropriate solution IMO. If all that needs to be done is to remove columns that are well defined by their delimiters, than `cut` is the right tool for the job. However, the `-1` should be just `1` as there are no columns to the left of the first one.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -e 's/[ ].*[ ]/ /' yourfile
```

This looks at the leftmost space and up till the rightmost space and replaces this with a single space. IOW, first & last fields are retained.

Assuming that there are no leading &/or trailing spaces. There are no TABs.

Otherwise, we can always do the following:

```
SPC=`echo 'x' | tr 'x' '\040'`
TAB=`echo 'x' | tr 'x' '\011'`
WS="[$TAB$SPC]"
sed -e "s/^$WS*//;s/${WS}\$//;s/${WS}.*${WS}/${SPC}/" < yourfile
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ echo "a.b.gg3d 0000000001 0000000001 y" |sed -r 's/[ ]+[0-9]+//g'
a.b.gg3d y
```

-r regex mode

You're searching for one or more spaces, followed by one or more numbers of any in range 0-9.  Technically this is matching twice, leaving your third space in between a.b.gg3d and y.